# What to call elements next to each other in a finite subset of an infinite set?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Assume I have a finite subset $D$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. Does anyone know a name for the property of two elements $e_1, e_2 \in D$ having $\lnot \exists e_3\in D: e_1 < e_3 < e_2 $?

Comment: It’s perfectly acceptable simply to say that $e_1$ and $e_2$ are *adjacent* in $D$. You can also say that $e_2$ is the immediate successor of $e_1$ in $D$ and that $e_1$ is the immediate predecessor of $e_2$ in $D$.

Comment: I don't want use cover or adjacent, because I work on a graph, which vertices have elements in $D$. It would be rather confusing using cover or adjacent in context of graph theory for this. But immediate successor or predecessor sounds good. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In this case $e_2$ is said to **cover** $e_1$. See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation)